# inspect style edit ( microsoft edge)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, web-frontend, inspect

how to prevent inspect editing from affecting my code in editor ?
cause when i edit styles in inspect it also edits my editor css styles at the same time
( microsoft edge )

i tried searching in settings but didnot find anything

Answer (score 3):

Edge DevTools doesn't change your code. Refresh the page, it will be like previous one before making changes using DevTools.